# Error while while running trained topic model on new document

Tags: python, lda, topic-modeling, gensim

I have list of docs in `postCorp`. I am trying to get topics and corresponding probability using `lda model` that i have already trained using `gensim`.
Below is the code snippet where i am:
Getting each document
Converting it to BOW
Passing it to lda to return topics and 
And also calculating mean probability of each topic over all the document.

```
with open('ldaOutputPost','w') as out:
    topicMean = defaultdict(float)
    count = 0
    for corp in postCorp:
        count += 1
        for (t,p) in lda[dictionary.doc2bow(corp)]:
            topicMean[t] += p 
        out.write(str(lda[dictionary.doc2bow(corp)])+'\n')
```

This works fine if i just pass bow of one document. But when I loop over all the documents it gives me following error which I am unable to find out why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 110, in <module>
    for (t,p) in lda[dictionary.doc2bow(corp)]:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamodel.py", line 752, in __getitem__
    gamma, _ = self.inference([bow])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\ldamodel.py", line 380, in inference
    expElogbetad = self.expElogbeta[:, ids]
IndexError: index 6770 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 6770
```

Can any one please help.

P.S: There is no issue in BOW as `lda[dictionary.doc2bow(preCorp[0])` works fine and gives me correct output.

EDIT:
`postCorp` is list of list where inner list represents a list of all words in a document. Whereas dictionary is `dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(combined)` here combined is all corpus on which topic model was trained.

Comment: What is the source of `dictionary`, `postCorp` and `lda` ?

Comment: Everything is in reference to gensim. Here is reference for lda: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html

This is for dictionary: http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html

Comment: @mribot I am encountering the same issue, I suppose it is happening because the new document contains a word that was not included when the LDA was trained, but not sure.. How did you solve this?